# Trouble linking types to both dev and production in a monorepo

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, monorepo, pnpm

I have some trouble linking types to both dev and production in a pnpm workspace monorepo.
My IDE was yelling that it cannot find module '****' or its corresponding type declarations when I was importing a workspace package in another package or app.

To solve this I've added a types property to the individual package.json files of each package. In development mode the property points to `./src/index.ts` which works and resolve the error my IDE was giving me.

Unfortunately this does not work for the production build. Therefore the `types` property should point to `./dist/index.d.ts`

Anyone experienced the same and found a solution on how to fix both dev and production?